# Moving from Java Spring to Spring.NET

Tags: c#, spring.net, spring-data-jpa

I am a .NET programmer with very little Java experience. I have inherited a Java project and am attempting to do the Java to C# conversion by hand. I know that there are converters out there, but would prefer to do this by hand for the learning experience (there is no rush on this project).

Accordingly, I am wondering if somebody could answer the following:

1) What, exactly, is the below logic doing with respect to the Jpa references:

```
public interface EbayListingRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<EbayListing>, JpaRepository<EbayListing, Long> {
```

2) I have installed Spring.NET and added Spring.Core, Spring.Data and Spring.Data.NHibernate. I am trying to reproduce the logic the above-mentioned "EbayListingRepository" class which has the following imports (from the java class):

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
```

Spring.NET's Spring.Data doesn't seem to have "Data.Domain" or "Data.Jpa". Can somebody explain what the equivalent in .NET is here. Also, how do I go about reproducing the code in question #1 for .NET?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is a JSR, I don't think there is something equivalent.  You can tried iKVM, which can help you directly covert Java binary to .NET.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I am not looking to convert my binary int executables, but rather make conversions at the code-level. I would really like to know what all the JPA code would look like in .NET or, what kind of tools would achieve the same result. Thanks again.